# How do I make keep these values from rewriting into the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a small piece of code that is writing some values into a textarea inside a form. The write whenever I click a button. However if I click the button more than once they will write over and over. I need to be able to click the button multiple times (for example if the user changes a value) and have the values that I am writing simply refresh rather than repeat. Here is what I have...

```
var endwallPanelLengths = [totalHeightInches];
    var i = 0;
    while (endwallPanelLengths[i] > eaveInches) 
    {
        endwallPanelLengths.push(endwallPanelLengths[i] - peakHeightDecrease);
        document.getElementById("test83").value += "4 - " + endwallPanelLengths[i] + "\n";
        i++;
    }
```

When I click the button the first time the values are correct however they write again after everytome i click it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do the whole iteration when the user change a value. Then you just need to reset the value of the textarea to empty before the loop. Something like this:

```
var endwallPanelLengths = [totalHeightInches];
var i = 0;
document.getElementById("test83").value = '';  //Reset the value
while (endwallPanelLengths[i] > eaveInches) {
    endwallPanelLengths.push(endwallPanelLengths[i] - peakHeightDecrease);
    document.getElementById("test83").value += "4 - " + endwallPanelLengths[i] + "\n";
    i++;
}
```

I have worked out a [demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/DyVYE/1/). Hope that is what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
    document.getElementById("test83").value += "4 - " + endwallPanelLengths[i] + "\n";
```

you're appending a value to `test83`. Presumably (since I can't see your html!!!) you just need to remove the `+` from the `+=`.

EDIT: in case you want to append all of the values in your loop, and nothing else, simply clear the value before you enter your loop and leave the `+=`

```
document.getElementById("test83").value = "";
var endwallPanelLengths = [totalHeightInches];
......
```

Comment: I think the OP want to do the whole while loop each time the user changes a value. Change "+=" to "=" will only have the last value in the textarea.

Comment: ah, seems reasonable. Since they didn't put their html! I'll put an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var endwallPanelLengths = [totalHeightInches];
var i = 0;
document.getElementById("test83").value = '';
while (endwallPanelLengths[i] > eaveInches) 
{
    endwallPanelLengths.push(endwallPanelLengths[i] - peakHeightDecrease);
    document.getElementById("test83").value += "4 - " + endwallPanelLengths[i] + "\n";
    i++;
}
```

I'm assuming that all the code is executed eacht time you click the button, am I right ?

Comment: didn't recognize my answer is the same to yours. Sorry, upvoted your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement a clickEventhandler that checks whether or not your texts exists.....